# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'atlassian' docker container

Tags: python, docker

I have a dockerfile as shown below:

```
FROM python:3.7.9
WORKDIR /csr
COPY . /csr/
RUN python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY main.py /csr/
CMD ["python3", "main.py"]
```

`requirements.txt`:

```
atlassian
pandas
```

docker container shows that `atlassian` is installed:

```
root@41675649fc2f:/csr# pip3 list
Package            Version
------------------ -----------
atlassian          0.0.0
```

However the module import throwing error:

```
docker run csr_python

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    import confluence_csr
  File "/csr/confluence_csr.py", line 2, in <module>
    from atlassian import Confluence
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'atlassian'
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: Can you execute these commands in the docker container and show us the output: `pip3 --version` and `python3 -- version`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `atlassian-python-api` instead of `atlassian`in **requirements.txt**.

Here is some [examples](https://pypi.org/project/atlassian-python-api/).